# Laravel count distinct value and get as associative array of key value pair

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent

I have a field called language in my table submission. Here the different user has submitted their problem with different language such as java(56) 5 times, CPP(45) 7 times, and python(71) 10 times.

I want to have a query in laravel with eloquent such that it returns an array or  with key-value pair as

`$user_lang = ['56'=>5,'45'=>7,'71'=>10]`

here 56,45,71 are the id of the languages

Answer (score 0):

If you have prepared data like count of how many times, you can simply use pluck method. eg

```
$user_lang = Language::where(<condition>)->pluck('times', 'id');
```

It will return the array as you desired.

If you do not have prepared count, then count it using group by and simply use same pluck method .

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = Submission::selectRaw('id', 'COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS times'))
->groupBy(id)
->get();

$user_lang = [];

$result->map($result, function($item){
  $user_lang[$item->id] = $item->times;
});
```